# How can I get responseHeaders() from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineLoadingInfo()

Tags: pyqt6, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

Here is a code example

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineLoadingInfo
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebEngineView()
    view.load(QUrl('https://duckduckgo.com'))
    page = view.page()
    info = QWebEngineLoadingInfo().responseHeaders()
    response_headers = page.loadingChanged(info)
    print(response_headers)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

How can I receive http response headers after each loading?
I tried to do this:

```
page = view.page()
info = QWebEngineLoadingInfo().responseHeaders()
response_headers = page.loadingChanged(info)
print(response_headers)
```

But this returns an error:

```
TypeError: QWebEngineLoadingInfo(other: QWebEngineLoadingInfo): not enough arguments
```

Comment: Simply connect a slot (i.e. a function that receives a *loadinginfo* object) to the [loadingChanged signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginepage.html#loadingChanged) (but do this *before* trying to load any urls). You obviously cannot access such information until the page has actually loaded, which happens *asynchronously* - so your code must wait until the signal fires and then act appropriately. If you're not familiar with the concept of signals and slots, I suggest you [consult a tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-gui-calculator/#signals-and-slots).